# Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$(x_1+t.y_1,...,x_n+t.y_n)\mapsto f(x_1+t.y_1,...x_n+t.y_n)$ with $t\in \mathbb{R}$

I have to determine $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x_1+t.y_1,...,x_n+t.y_n)}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Let $z_i(t)=x_i+t.y_i$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$.

We have : $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x_1+t.y_1,...,x_n+t.y_n)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d} f(z_1(t),...,z_n(t))}{\mathrm{d}t}= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(z_1(t),...,z_n(t))}{\partial z_i}.\frac{\mathrm{d}z_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}y_i\frac{\partial f(z_1(t),...,z_n(t))}{\partial z_i}$

But the problem is that in my book they found :

$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(\big(z_j(t)\big)_{1\le j \le n})}{\partial x_i}.z_i'(t)$

Why do they use $x_i$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It is a typo...

Comment: No, it's not a typo. You start with a function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and you want to denote its $i$th partial derivative. That is $\partial f/\partial x_i$. Similarly, in single-variable calculus, if you start with $f(x)$ and want to differentiate $g(t)=f(t^2)$, the correct answer is $g'(t)=f'(t^2)2t = 2t \dfrac{df}{dx}\Big|_{x=t^2}$.

Comment: This notation means tye derivative with respect to the $i$ variable, whatever name it is given.

Comment: @FelixKlein Is my notation correct or maybe should I put $z_i(t)$ instead of $z_i$ ?

Comment: I would leave it as in the book.